# Postman - How to show multiple Response and Request examples in documentation

Tags: postman

I'm trying to create a documentation for my Postman collection. For some of the APIs I want to show multiple response examples and for some I want to show multiple request examples as well. I think this would help the people reading the documentation a bit more.

Here is the problem,

1. I've saved multiple responses as example for some APIs but only the
   first one shows up in the documentation.
2. I couldn't find an option to add multiple request examples for same API.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to achieve here ? If yes, then how do I do it ?

**UPDATE 1:** The multiple responses I added was actually displayed in the documentation. There was a dropdown to view different response examples. My bad. Still not sure how to add multiple request examples for an API though.

**UPDATE 2:** It looks like the request was also getting saved with the response as example and the dropdown mentioned in UPDATE 1 updates different request examples also. So all my issue are solved.

Comment: Please don't add "Solved" to the title of your question. Please accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **UPDATE 1** and **UPDATE 2** I've made in this question the issue is solved for me now. Keeping the post in case anyone else faces same issue.

> **UPDATE 1:** The multiple responses I added was actually displayed in the documentation. There was a dropdown to view different response
> examples.
>
> **UPDATE 2:** It looks like the request was also getting saved with the response as example and the dropdown mentioned in **UPDATE 1** updates
> different request examples also. So all my issue are solved.